# Qt HTTP GET freezes screen

Tags: qt, http, networking, request

I'm writing a Qt program to get an image from site and insert in a QLabel. When I send my request my screen freezes and nothing more occurs.
Notice I'm new in Qt.

Based on my initial knowledge of Qt it's enough send a signal when download is finished.

```
...

MapReader::MapReader(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    imageLabelMap = ui.imageMap;
    getImageButton = ui.getImageButton;
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    setup();
}

MapReader::~MapReader()
{
}

void MapReader::setup()
{
    QObject::connect(getImageButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(triggerDownload()));
    QObject::connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finishedDownload(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void MapReader::setImage(QByteArray imageBytes)
{
    QImage map;
    ...
}

void MapReader::triggerDownload()
{   
    QUrl url("http://images.tsn.ca/images/stories/2012/09/26/terrydunfield_2035-430x298.jpg");
    QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
}

void MapReader::finishedDownload(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
        msgBox.setInformativeText("Error on downloading file: \n"+reply->errorString());
        msgBox.exec();
        return;
    }
    QVariant attribute = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    if (attribute.isValid())
    {
        QUrl url = attribute.toUrl();
        qDebug() << "must go to:" << url;
        return;
    }

    setImage(reply->readAll());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some code missing that might give us a clue. You have

```
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
```

But I don't see where loop is defined? Sounds like you are running an additional event loop?

Regardless, you don't need that. This should be as simple as:

```
void MapReader::triggerDownload()
{   
    QUrl url("http://images.tsn.ca/images/stories/2012/09/26/terrydunfield_2035-430x298.jpg");
    QNetworkReply* reply = networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(finishedDownload()));
}

void MapReader::finishedDownload()
{
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender()); // sender() allows us to see who triggered this slot - in this case the QNetworkReply

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if(reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
        msgBox.setInformativeText("Error on downloading file: \n"+reply->errorString());
        msgBox.exec();
        return;
    }
    QVariant attribute = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    if (attribute.isValid())
    {
        QUrl url = attribute.toUrl();
        qDebug() << "must go to:" << url;
        return;
    }

    setImage(reply->readAll());
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Make sure you have defined finishedDownload() as a slot in your header file

Comment: I've tried your solution, but the problem remains. It freezes exactly when I call networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(url)). I don't think if this info is useful. I'm on a local college network and I'm using their internet access to do this. We don't have any content blocked. Because I'm on a local network I can't do this?

Comment: I think it must be related to your network, as I just tried this exact code here and it works fine. I would suggest running the HTTP example provided with Qt [http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-http.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-http.html) and seeing if that works. Also look at the qDebug() output for clues.

Comment: docster thanks for your help. The problem remains on VS2010. My version is the Ultimate edition. My assumption is a bug inside Qt Addin. I've run this code without any modification on QtCreator and works very fine. I don't know because this behavior occurs. So, I'll use QtCreator.